# Scrolling through images smartly

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiscrollview

Part of the App I am developing will have an image viewer section. Below is a screenshot of how the view is laid out.

[image]

I want the bottom to be horizontally scrollable throughout the images. I am not 100% how I would go about this and would really appreciate any advise/tutorials/answers. I know I will need to store my images in an array (which I will populate from my CoreData instance) and populate them into the mini image views but I don't know how I can 're-use' the image views as I scroll through, to save on memory. I have had a look at the WWDC video for 'Designing Apps with Scroll Views' but this isn't exactly what I am trying to achieve, as I have multiple image views on the view at once.

Any help would be very much appreciated, I am quite new to iOS Development just so you know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at UICollectionView as it's pretty much designed for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have looked into UICollectionView but it doesnt let you have 1 central image like mine about. It is more lots of thumbnails.

Comment: He means that the bottom view is a uicollectionview horizontally scrollable, and the big image is a simple image view. That will allow you to reuse the collection view's items, which have your images.

Comment: A simple search also showed me this pod https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/thumbnaillistview
Don't know if is updated, but is pretty much what you are trying to do, missing some ui tweaks.

Comment: Oh OK, my mistake sorry guys. Thanks very much, this seems to be what I am looking for. I will mark this as the correct answer! Thanks again guys!